# Find & instantiate annotated Scala classes in a specified package

Tags: scala, reflection, jvm

I want to build a simple 'rake' style command line tool that will allow me to define tasks in scala (that can optionally take additional command line arguments) that will be automatically loaded and accessible through a single main() method, to provide a single point of entry and minimize generating lots of wrapper scripts.

An example of what I'm looking for is Jersey, which will automatically load all annotated classes in a specified package and create REST endpoints.  What's the right way to do this in scala?  Basically, I just want to end up with a collection of instances of every class in a 
package with a given annotation (which all have a Task trait or are a subclass of Trait, etc.)

Comment: wait a bit for full scala reflection to come in 2.10 version of Scala :)